# Returning A Function With Strings

Tags: python

Directions:  Write a program that receives the length of two pieces of fabric in feet and inches (as whole numbers) and returns the total as a String in the format: Feet: 7 Inches: 3 (link to website using https://codingbat.com/prob/p267045?parent=/home/bryce.hulett@hotmail.com

total(5, 11, 1, 4) → 'Feet: 7 Inches: 3'

total(0, 1, 1, 4) → 'Feet: 1 Inches: 5'

total(3, 6, 2, 6) → 'Feet: 6 Inches: 0'

Code:

```
def total(first_f,first_i,second_f,second_i):
  inches = (first_i + second_i) % 12
  feet = first_f + second_f
  additional_f = (first_i + second_i) // 12
  total = f'Feet: {feet+additional_f}  Inches: {inches}'
  return total
```

My return isn't getting the output I need... I'm not sure what else to do since it worked on a different website. It says invalid syntax error, but if I delete the "f" that's causing it shows

```
'Feet: {feet+additional_f} Inches: {inches}'
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I ran your code and get the correct output

Comment: are you using python 3.7?

Comment: @Mike67 did you run it on the website?

Comment: @yhenon I'm on a chromebook and I have to use repl.it, so I have no idea.

Comment: Got it - Use `total = 'Feet: ' + str(feet+additional_f) + ' Inches: ' + str(inches)` All tests pass with this change.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are returning `f'Feet: {feet+additional_f}  Inches: {inches}'`, you have to `print` it out, and you will see the result

```
def total(first_f,first_i,second_f,second_i):
  inches = (first_i + second_i) % 12
  feet = first_f + second_f
  additional_f = (first_i + second_i) // 12
  total = f'Feet: {feet+additional_f}  Inches: {inches}'
  return total 
print(total(5, 11, 1, 4))
```

Result :

```
Feet: 7  Inches: 3
```

If it doesn't works for you change `total` with This:

```
total = 'Feet: '+ str(feet+additional_f) + ' Inches: '+ str(inches)
```